# How do I make custom labels visible in a GitLab CE group board?

Tags: gitlab

I am running a GitLab CE instance. I have:

- created a group, with projects in that group
- defined group-level labels
- marked a project issue with one of those labels

When I first visited the group board I was presented with the option to use the default labels ("To do" and "Doing") or define my own. I picked "define my own". But my existing labels do not appear in the board.

How do I make these custom labels visible in a my group board?

Comment: cross-posted: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/20770

Comment: cross-posted: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/8393

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems defining your own group labels ("Configurable issue boards") is not a GitLab CE feature. So you cannot do this.

From https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/issue_board.html#summary-of-features-per-tier ...

Tier: Core / Free
Number of Project Issue Boards: 1
Number of Group Issue Boards: 1
**Configurable Issue Boards: No**
Assignee Lists: No

This option was offered on a CE/EE instance, which seems like a bug https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/8393